How do I Preview docx files in lwc where document have multiple pages?
I have built custom LWC component to preview files in Salesforce so that file preview window is open on onclick event and it only show image without other buttons(download,share, public Link) that salesforce standard preview window show.
handleImagePreview(event) {
        const fileId = event.target.dataset.id;
        const file = this.imageFiles.find(file => file.Id === fileId);
        if (file) {
            this.imageUrl = `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=${file.Id}&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=${file.ContentDocumentId}`;
            this.modalTitle = file.Title;
            this.showImageModal = true;
        }
    }

Now it works fine for images like jpg png and all but when I click on .docx files, it only show page=0
Here When I click preview button there are 3 request I see in Network Log in following order
1
Request URL:
https://mydomain.trailblaze.lightning.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=068bm0000031JQHAA2&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=069bm000003cVYvAAM
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
301 Moved Permanently

2
Request URL:
https://mydomain.trailblaze.file.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=068bm0000031JQHAA2&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=069bm000003cVYvAAM
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
301 Moved Permanently

3
Request URL:
https://mydomain.trailblaze.file.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=068bm0000031JQH&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=05Tbm000003Jp6j&page=0
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK

Is there page parameter I can pass in this? and how to handle multiple page?
this.imageUrl = `/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId=${file.Id}&operationContext=CHATTER&contentId=${file.ContentDocumentId}`;


This question is similar to: How can I preview an entire file with lwc in community?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
